# Deploying app on heroku problem with compailer

Tags: heroku

[Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV32X.png)
I have a problem while pushing my app on heroku.

Frontend works fine locally, backend works fine to.

The first message is an error about footer component on react,  telling that is not written properly. I check everything about the import request of this component and everything is fine.  There is no import of footer in homepage component only in app.
While I'm pushing my project to heroku I got errors in shell...

Full error in CMD [shell view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWtWS.png)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! Project@ build: `react-scripts build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the Project@ build script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

[App.js view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cxWp.png)

Comment: So, the first line looks to me like it's expecting to find your FooterComponent at the path `/Homepage/FooterComponent/`. Is that where the FooterComponent.js file actually is? Without seeing your project structure, or any additional info, it makes it difficult to know for sure.

Comment: I put the photo up, bgaynor78. On first, FooterComponent was imported in homepage without calling it in body like component. I realize that,  and I deleted import. The true and right import is in app and its imported properly. After I do that the problem error is the same with FooterCOmponent.

Comment: Can you provide what your App.js looks like?

Comment: I put it up. :)

Comment: Are you doing a named export in your FooterComponent? Like `export { FooterComponent };`? As opposed to `export FooterComponent;`. From what you've shown I don't see a reason the FooterComponent shouldn't be found.

Comment: When I did {FooterComponent} instead "export default FoooterComponent" and changed the function to const not to the class. I make it. Thanks bgyanor78